# Getting issue in CGPath Scale

Tags: ios, cgpath, cashapelayer

I am drawing polygon using `CGPath` and adding to `CAShapeLayer`.I want to scale my `CGPath` when user click on it. I know how to scale `CGPath`. But when i click my `CGPath`, my `CGPath` drawing far from centre while i am drawing polygon in centre.

```
CGAffineTransform scaleTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
CGPathRef oldPath = polygonLayer.path;
CGPathRef scaledPath = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(oldPath, &scaleTransform);
polygonLayer.path = scaledPath;
```

Comment: so what is the problem ? What are your seeing on screen which not as per your needs ?

Comment: I have drawn polygon and then trying to scale it,when i am scaling polygon,scaled polygon is drawing at different place.Not where i have drawn initial polygon.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you're used to UIView transformation, which is done from the center of the view.
CGPath transformation is done on the points (imagine `CGPointZero` as the center of the path).
My solution: translate to CGPointZero , scale , and then back to your original coordinates.

```
CGPathRef CGPath_NGCreateCopyByScalingPathAroundCentre(CGPathRef path,
                                           const float scale)
{
    CGRect bounding = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(path);
    CGPoint pathCenterPoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounding), CGRectGetMidY(bounding));

    CGAffineTransform translateAndScale = CGAffineTransformTranslate( CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale), - pathCenterPoint.x, -pathCenterPoint.y) ;
    CGAffineTransform translateBack = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(pathCenterPoint.x, pathCenterPoint.y);

    CGPathRef centeredAndScaled = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(path, &translateAndScale);
    CGPathRef translatedPathRef = CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(centeredAndScaled, &translateBack);

    CGPathRelease(centeredAndScaled);

    return translatedPathRef;
}
```